# Meta-analysis with rma() in metafor

Tags: data-visualization, meta-analysis, cohens-d, forest-plot

I am working on a meta-analysis that has two moderator variables. Below is the code that I've figured out, but I'm not sure how to get the forest plot to show the overall model estimate. It's currently showing the effect sizes for each study, but is not taking into account the task or the display type to give me an overall effect size for each task/display type combination.

```
ma_model_1 <- rma(cohensD, varD, mods = ~factor(Task)+factor(Display), method = "REML",weighted = FALSE, data = acc) 
summary(ma_model_1)
forest(ma_model_1, order = "resid", slab = paste(acc$ID), addpred=TRUE, header=TRUE,xlim=c(-12,7))
```

[image]

Questions:

1. Is my rma() model specified correctly with the moderators?
2. Why does the forest plot have the light gray symbols with error bars in addition to the black ones?
3. How do I get the forest plot to break down the effect sizes by moderators?
4. How do I get the forest plot to show the overall model effect size? It works without the moderators included, but when I add them it removes that piece of information.

Thank you.

Comment: See: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:computing_adjusted_effects Also, why are you using `weighted=FALSE`?

Comment: @Wolfgang Thank you for this link - I am checking this out today. As for your question, I already computed the weighted effect sizes in my excel csv file. I believe that weighted=FALSE is telling the function not to weight any of my effect sizes since they are already weighted. Am I using that setting correctly?

Comment: No, you generally don't want to do that. Let the software handle they weighting for you. For example, in random-effects models, the weights depend on the amount of heterogeneity and you cannot "pre-compute" that.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thank you for the information on this. I'll make sure to use my unweighted values and let the function compute the weighting.